# Android - Add deep link for my website home page

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, deeplink

I implemented before many deep links for my website pages in my Android app, like product page, category page, and everything is okay.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.CategoryActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/category/"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But currently I want to add a deep link to my website home page in the Android app and I tried many things like this:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.HomeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
                // android:path="" // (1) not working
                // android:pathPattern="{0,1}" // (2) not working
                // android:path="/" // (3) it will work
                // (4) I also removed the path and it worked.
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

(3) it will work if it tested using the adb but in the Chrome Google search results my website will not be with "/" at the end.

(4) it will work but it will work also for all the other deep links also! (for http://mywebsite/product/434 and http://mywebsite/category/434) moreover when I click on my home page link from chrome Google results two icons of my app will appear!

How can I solve this problem and apply the deep link for my website home page without be conflicted with the other deep links?

Note: my last resort will be to redirect all the deep links to specific xActivity and inside the xActivity I will process all the deep links in a proper way but I don't think it is good idea.

Comment: Is my question clear or not?

Comment: It seems on Android L and above try #3 will work correctly without any problems, but for Android K and lower the result will be as described in #3